# Confirmation Dialog on back button press event Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am stuck at one point in Xamarin.Forms application

On Back button press simply I want to ask user to confirm whether he really wants to exit or not,
"OnBackButtonPressed" I want to show Alert dialog and proceed as user response.

But "OnBackButtonPressed" is not Async I cannot write await DisplayAlert...
Please direct me how should i implement this feature?

I am using ContentPage as my root Page of NavigationPage

```
    public class frmHome : ContentPage
```

Here is the code :

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    var result = await  this.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Do you really want to exit?", "Yes", "No");

    if (result)
        {
            //user wants to exit
            //Terminate application
        }
        else
        {
            //Dont do anything
        }
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() => {
            var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Do you really want to exit?", "Yes", "No");
            if (result) await this.Navigation.PopAsync(); // or anything else
        });

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Daniel, using your code I have a compile error  The return type of an async method must be void, Task, or Task<T>

Comment: This does not work. Press Yes or No on the alert, it remains on the same page.

Comment: This doesn't work , I need to return false but this is anonymous function.
If I assign a value and check after the function, it will always be set to false since the checking will not wait for the Alert. Please help

Answer (score 6):

Here's the code that worked for me

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Do you really want to exit?", "Yes", "No");

            if (result)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().CloseMainWindow(); // Or anything else
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Great ! This code worked for me also. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Easy way to override hardware back button and show a confirmation dialog box to user

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        if (await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Are you sure you want to go back ?", "Yes", "No"))
        {
            base.OnBackButtonPressed();

            await Navigation.PopAsync();
         }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Easy way to override hardware back button and show a confirmation dialog box to user

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mainpage and want to exit your app then this code will help you.

In your UI (PCL)

```
  protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
            {

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(new Action(async () => {
                    var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Do you really want to exit?", "Yes", "No");

                    if (result)
                    {
                        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                            DependencyService.Get<IAndroidMethods>().CloseApp();
                    }
                }));
                return true;
            }
```

Also create an Interface (in your UI PCL):

```
public interface IAndroidMethods
{
    void CloseApp();
}
```

Now implement the Android-specific logic in your Android project:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AndroidMethods))]
namespace Your.Namespace
{
   public class AndroidMethods : IAndroidMethods
   {
       public void CloseApp()
       {
             var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
            activity.FinishAffinity();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    RunOnUiThread(
        async () =>
        {
            var isCloseApp = await AlertAsync(this, "NameOfApp", "Do you want to close this app?", "Yes", "No");

            if (isCloseApp)
            {
                var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
                activity.FinishAffinity();
            }
        });
}

public Task<bool> AlertAsync(Context context, string title, string message, string positiveButton, string negativeButton)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    using (var db = new AlertDialog.Builder(context))
    {
        db.SetTitle(title);
        db.SetMessage(message);
        db.SetPositiveButton(positiveButton, (sender, args) => { tcs.TrySetResult(true); });
        db.SetNegativeButton(negativeButton, (sender, args) => { tcs.TrySetResult(false); });
        db.Show();
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

[Xamarin.Android await AlertDialog.Builder](https://medium.com/@dannyc/xamarin-android-await-alertdialog-builder-42d9c861e37a)

Comment: The concept help me in xamarin.forms, thanks you gave me a great idea an it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am done like this

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    var result = await  this.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Do you really want to exit?", "Yes", "No");

    if (result)
        {
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().CloseMainWindow();
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Close();
        }
        else
        {
            //Dont do anything
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private async void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Do you really want to exit?", "Yes", "No");
            if (result)
            {

                var menuitem = sender as MenuItem;
                string name = menuitem.BindingContext as string;

                lielements.Remove(name);
            }
            else
            {


            }

        }
```

Comment: Dear, Question is not about dialogue result. It was about onBackPressed event