# Navigate Back to first shell item

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

Hello I'm with this problem where I need to go back to my first Shell Item, since I don't know how and google search hasn't helped I'm asking here.

```
 <ShellItem Route="ChoicePage" >
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ChoicePage}" />
</ShellItem>
<ShellItem Route="LoginPage" >
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
</ShellItem>
<TabBar Route="MainPage">
    <Tab Title="{helpers:Translate Explore}" 
         Icon="explore.png" 
         Route="ExplorePage">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ExplorePage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="{helpers:Translate Plan}" 
         Icon="globe.png" 
         Route="NextTripsPage">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NextTripsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="{helpers:Translate Trips}" 
         Icon="around.png" 
         Route="MyTripsPage">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MyTripsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab
        Title="{helpers:Translate Map}"
        Icon="map.png"
        Route="MyMap">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:FullMapPage }" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab
        Title="{helpers:Translate MeTextProfile}"
        Icon="me.png"
        Route="MyProfilePage">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MyProfilePage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

I have this 2 shells items and when the users go to `ExplorePage` or any `TabBar` I want to set the back button to go back to `ChoicePage`. I have tried to add `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");` but with no luck even `PopToRootAsync()`  doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override the default behavior of navigation back button (soft, not physical button) in some specific pages than you need to set the attached [Shell.BackButtonBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#back-button-behavior) in those pages:

`ExplorePage.xaml`

```
<ContentPage ...>    
    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior Command="{Binding BackCommand}"/>   
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

#### ViewModel

```
public Command BackCommand { get; set; } =  new Command(
         async () => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(ChoicePage)));
```

if you want the physical back button to behave the same way too then you need to override [OnBackButtonPressed()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onbackbuttonpressed?view=xamarin-forms) in your page's code-behind, related question [Confirmation Dialog on back button press event Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32163471)

Comment: I did that, but since its a tabbed page the tab bar is still visible, I need to go back to the start where the tab bar doesn't show up.

Comment: Sorry for not responding to this thread. I accepted @Cfun answer.